# transactional replication using script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-agent, transactional-replication

I am able to configure transactional replication using SSMS and it works properly. But i want to configure it using script so that i use it from my c#/vb application.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you complete all the step of transactional replication using SSMS then it's not complicated to do with the script.

Just carefully observe that when you configure distribution, publication and subscription SSMS gives you the option to generate script in every step.

You can use that generated script.

But only difference is when you add articles to publication. You can use the following code to add article

```
declare @name nvarchar(50)
declare curname cursor for
select name from sysobjects where type = 'U'
open curname
fetch next from curname into @name
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
if exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
begin
exec sp_addarticle
@publication = N'publication_name', @article = @name, @source_owner = N'dbo',
@source_object = @name, @type = N'logbased', @description = null, @creation_script = null,
@pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F,
@identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual', @destination_table = @name,
@destination_owner = N'dbo', @vertical_partition = N''
end
fetch next from curname into @name
end
close curname
deallocate curname
```

Or, you can see https://hasibarnab.wordpress.com/category/sql-server/replication/

Comment: [sysname](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a better type for @name. Your script would not work for names longer than 50 characters. sysname is the internal type of object names and equivalent to nvarchar(128).

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @returncode int
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "C:\thePackage.dtsx"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out sp_addpublication, sp_addarticle, and sp_addsubscription in BOL.